# How to count numbers of row of sql query in joomla and display it?

Tags: php, sql, joomla

My sql query is this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOrders FROM table_products where published = 1;
```

Joomla use Jdatabase to play with tables. I found this on internet:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
 $query = $db->getQuery(true); 
 $query->select(array('name', 'email', 'username')) 
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__my_users')) 
   ->where($db->quoteName('name') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'%SMITH%\'')); 
 $db->setQuery($query); 

 // get the count 
 $my_count = $db->getNumRows(); 

 // retrieve the data 
 $rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 

 echo $my_count;
```

So I try to modify this example for my query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
 $query = $db->getQuery(true); 
 $query->select(array('id')) 
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__table_products')) 
   ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('1')); 

 $db->setQuery($query); 

 // get the count 
 $my_count = $db->getNumRows(); 

 // retrieve the data 
 $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

But it doesn't work. I get empty result. What is wrong?

Someone can help me please?

Regards

Comment: I don't know anything about this syntax, but have you tried using `quoteName('table_products')` and/or replacing `LIKE` with `=`?  I'm also not seeing a reason to quote a numeric value.

Comment: For guidance on writing a secure `LIKE` statement with `%` in Joomla syntax, [go here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352).

Answer (score 4):

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$my_count = $db->query();
$my_count = $db->getNumRows();
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for your answer?

Comment: The second line aka `$my_count = $db->query();` seems pretty pointless here.

Comment: @RiA it seems pointless but it is necessary, otherwise `$my_count` is NULL

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to COUNT number of rows, but i am not sure about

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_products'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'%1%\''));

$db->setQuery($query);
$count = $db->loadResult();
```

SEE MORE:https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->select('COUNT(*) AS NoumberOfRows');
```

Answer (score 0):

The $db->getNumRows() should be called right after the $db->execute();
In that case, it will return the number of selected rows.

Comment: According to https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase (way at the bottom) it seems that $db->getNumRows(); still works in Joomla 3.x?

Comment: Tried it, and get Mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource ... So how does one count the number of rows affected with an update query (for example)?

Comment: Jimmy, you are right about that one!
About the number of rows after a update, there is a function in php mysql_affected_rows, but i'm not sure if there is a Joomla equivalent of it

Comment: For those researching, follow [Jimmy's quest](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14424/12352)

Comment: Haha! Funny comment @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing `$db->execute();` before

```
// get the count 
$my_count = $db->getNumRows();
```

From the documentation "To get a result from getNumRows() you have to run it after the query and before you have retrieved any results."

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#getNumRows.28.29

Answer (score 0):

the easy way

```
$rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 

$numberRows=count($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code. Hope will help.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
->select($db->quoteName(array('column_name_here')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name_here'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
print_r($num_rows);
$result = $db->loadRowList();   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code Example.

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query='SELECT * FROM table_products where published = 1';
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 
$my_count=count($rows);
echo $my_count; 
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @metalbox shared this insight half of a decade earlier.